# What does this group look like?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$, and consider the field rational fractions of $t$, $F(t)$. Consider these two automorphisms:
$$ \sigma :t \mapsto -t$$
$$ \tau: t \mapsto 1-t$$
I managed to prove that $\left<\sigma,\tau\right>$ is actually finite (via induction). Here are some results:
$$ \sigma^2 = I = \tau^2$$
$$\sigma\tau: t \mapsto t-1$$
$$\tau\sigma: t \mapsto t+1$$
$$\tau\sigma\tau: t \mapsto 2-t$$
$$\sigma\tau\sigma: t \mapsto -t-1$$
$$\sigma\tau\sigma\tau: t \mapsto 2+t$$
$$\tau\sigma\tau\sigma: t \mapsto -2+t$$
$$\sigma\tau\sigma\tau\sigma: t \mapsto -2-t$$
$$\tau\sigma\tau\sigma\tau: t \mapsto 3-t$$
And so on until eventualy, some sequence of $\tau\sigma...\sigma\tau$ will reach $\pm p \pm t$, returning to $\sigma$ or to $I$. My questions are: How many elements does this group have? It clearly depends on $p$. Also, what group is it isomorphic to? I also managed to find this element in $\text{Fix}(\left<\sigma,\tau\right>)$:
$$ q(t) = (t^p - t)^2$$
However it is not clear to me whether $\text{Fix}(\left<\sigma,\tau\right>) = F(q)$

Comment: In general, any group generated by two elements -- both of which have order 2 -- is dihedral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For odd $p$, it is the dihedral group of order $2p$, consisting
of $t\mapsto\pm t+a$ for $a\in\Bbb F_p$.

$F(t)$ therefore has degree $2p$ over the fixed field of the group.

Comment: Why "odd"? Does it not work for $p=2$?

Comment: If $p = 2$ It is called the Klein 4 group. Or $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$